# Most elegant way work with collection

Tags: java, android

I have list of object who have field - title. Need to collect title in list. I do it in code below. But, maybe it possible do more elegant? Thanks.

```
ArrayList<String> organizationTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Organization organization : result){
    organizationTitles.add(organization.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: Not on Android.  Though it's not clear to me what you consider inelegant about that.

Comment: He doesn't like the loop. :P  No one likes the loops. Loops rule!

Comment: In python i can do it in single line use map, i just hope find in android some thing like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JDK 8, then yes. There are lambdas for your case:

```
result.forEach((Organization organization) -> organizationTitles.add(organization.getTitle()));
```

Which will do the exact same thing, but more compact. If you are using Java 7 however, there is no more elegant way (in my knowledge).

Edit: Just noted that you are on Android. I don't think Java 8 is supported already by it, so this is likely to not work.

Comment: This is not really encouraged I think. Adding to a collection inside internal loop is not functional programming. I would suggest to use Stream.map() instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you're in Java8, this is the perfect way to do:

```
List<String> organizationTitles = result.stream()
                                        .map(Organization::getTitle)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Then if you fail in love with that, [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html) is the place you wanna go further:

Answer (score 1):

If `result` is a `Collection` then you could do this:

```
result.stream().forEach( e -> {organizationTitles.add(e.getTitle);} );
```

Comment: This is not really encouraged I think. Adding to a collection inside internal loop is not functional programming. I would suggest to use Stream.map() instead.